# How to pass a variable coming from HTML to another django view function

Tags: python, django, ajax, function, view

**Intro:**
I've been looking for all stackoverflow questions but unfortunately after hours of research I cannot find a solution that suits my needs.
I have a variable generated after the user submits a form. I get this variable using an Ajax call and then I pass it to a django view.

---

file.html

```js
// if user clicked submit button, call ajax to pass variable to django view 
$('#submit').click(function() {
  var dato = 0;
  $.ajax({
    url: '{% url 'todo:get_dato' %}',
    dataType: 'text',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
      data: JSON.stringify(dato),
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {},
    error: function(xhr, status, error){}
  })    
});
```

---

**Problem:**
I can "receive" this variable into a django view function but I cannot pass `ajax_date` variable to another view function inside the same views.py file

---

views.py

1st function where I get ajax variable coming from HTML

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(staff_check)  
def get_dato(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'data' in request.POST:
        ajax_response_dict = json.loads(request.POST['data'])
        ajax_date = ajax_response_dict.get('date_id')
        request.session['ajax_date'] = ajax_date
```

2nd function where I need to use `ajax_date` variable

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(staff_check)
def calendario(request):
    form = EventForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
            
        #HERE I NEED TO USE VARIABLE
        ajax_date = request.session.get('ajax_date')
```

---

**Actual situation:**
What kind of `return` object should I use in get_dato() function?

If I print `ajax_date` from 2nd function I got:

```
None
<class 'NoneType'>
```

while inside the first function everything works:

`ajax_response_dict` is:

```
{'date_id': 0}
<class 'dict'>
```

`ajax_date` is:

```
0
<class 'int'>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What do you return from your views, can you share the responses? Setting this attr should make the session save `request.session.modified = True` but it depends on what the view returns

Comment: @IainShelvington The problem is that I don't know what to return inside the `get_dato` function, I tried many methods like `return render(request, ajax_date)` or `Jsonresponse` or `HttpResponse` but each of them gave a different error.

@AnkitTiwari I did not understand what you wrote

Comment: What error do the responses give? You need to return a proper response to get the session to save I believe

Comment: @IainShelvington what I should use? render? what args?

Comment: What action is triggering the `calendario` function? What url is it connected to? Why not pass optional get or post parameters to the url that triggers this function?

Comment: @Daniel I set two different urls: `path("calendario/", views.calendario, name="calendario"),` and 
`path("calendario/get_dato/", views.get_dato, name="get_dato"),` but actually I don't need the second url get_dato because I just need the variable into calendario() function just to know if user did something into html or not

Comment: Seems like you can add the `ajax_date` variable your form and pop it out in your view function. I am not following exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: To back up a bit, why handle the POST and form.save() in two separate views?  You may have a good reason, but it's not super evident to me.

Comment: @sc_props you're right there is no valid reason, I actually want to use just one view that is calendario()

Comment: I'd recommend bypassing the whole issue by handling your logic in a single view.  It's hard to suggest how without knowing your intent for the view, i.e., create, update, both?

Comment: @sc_props calendario() is a simple function that gets data from a user form and save them into database. At the moment it is working well. Now I wrote this ajax call because I want to know if user had set a value into html form that. Value could be 0 or 1, depending if  user set that value or not. If he set it, after form is submitted I need to write some code to execute this request from the user. I hope I was clear sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to separate your methods that render a template from those that do some sort of backend logic, for example:

**views.py**

```py
def render_index(request):
    
    ''' this method serves the index.html page only '''
    
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def submit_form(request):
    
    ''' this method unpacks a post request and does something with it '''

    # unpack request:
    date = request.POST.get('date')

    # do something with date
    ...

    # create the response:
    response = {'message':'OK'}

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

**index.html**

```html
<button id='btn'>Click Me!</button>
<script src="{% static 'scripts.js' %}"></script>
```

**scripts.js**

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {

  /* this method sends a post request to the backend */

  $.ajax({
    url : 'submit_form',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
      date : new Date(),
      ...
    },
    success : function(response) {

      /* this method executes on a successful response from the backend */
     
      var message = response.message
     
      // do something with the message, route user to new page, close form
      ...

    }

  });
});
```

Comment: You understood what I'm trying to achieve, but I tried your code and when I `print(date)` into django views.py it outputs `None`. I don't understand why it is the same as yours

Comment: Can you share your ajax post request?

Comment: $('#submit').click(function() {
 var id_data = {date_id: 0};
   $.ajax({
  url: '{% url 'todo:calendario' %}',
  type: "POST",
  data: {
  csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
  dato: id_data,
  },
  success: function(response){
  /* this method executes on a successful response from the backend */
  var message = response.message
  }
  }) 
    })

Comment: Can you check that all variable names are correct? Seems like there is a mixup between `dato` and `date`. Can you also print the post request in your view function? `print(request.POST)`

Comment: it returns all form fields filled by the user but not the ajax variable. I also tried using your example variable `date` but it does not work the same. It returns `None`. This is the output of `request.POST` `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['yUEAhUccxJsMWMsLLNbowX0pFa6J2cuMf3fzphRA5ce1EDL2VWxBXonp76e8ZtM3'], 'color': ['#0275d8'], 'title': ['test2'], 'allDay': ['on'], 'notify': ['on'], 'startTime': [''], 'endTime': [''], 'start': ['2022-02-27'], 'end': [''], 'startRecur': [''], 'endRecur': [''], 'daysOfWeek': [''], 'notify_time': ['1'], 'submit': ['Submit']}>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daniel I found the main error into Ajax call. The problem was the line `var id_data = {date_id: 0};`
The js variable was empty at starting point.

BUT there was another error I made, because I was trying to `print(dato)` after the line `if form.is_valid():` that's why I cannot get the value inside the existing view and I tried to make it work by using another view that is really useless for my goal